# A Good Point to Create Design Documents in CouchDb

Tags: couchdb, design-documents

I have a CouchDb instance running a peruser database configuration.

Each user database generated (when a user is added to the `_users` database) needs to have the same design documents with view/list logic etc.

What is the defacto way to add the design documents to the database upon database creation? Is it simply to add them after a successful user creation request? Or is there a more elegant way of doing this in CouchDb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a mechanism for initialize newly created user databases, you should include it in your user creation logic. 
If you want to decouple user creation and db initialization, I suggest you to explore the following strategy

1 - Create a template database and place on it your design documents that should be applied to every user db

2 - Listen continuously *_db_updates* endpoint where db level events will be notified. [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/follow) library can help you.

3 - When a db that matches the user db name pattern is created, you can trigger a replication from the template database to the newly created database using the *_replicate* endpoint.

Comment: Thanks - a good strategy. Also note cluxter's suggestion of the more recently maintained [Cloudant Follow](https://github.com/cloudant-labs/cloudant-follow) package.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on using the Follow npm module as @Juanjo Rodriguez suggested, please consider using the Cloudant's version. The Iriscouch's version (the one pointed by @Juanjo Rodriguez) is way out of date. For example it doesn't support CouchDB v2.x among other issues. I worked with the Cloudant's team to improve all this these last days and they just released the updated npm package yesterday here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudant-follow?activeTab=versions

The `0.17.0-SNAPSHOT.47` version embarks the patches we worked on so don't use the `0.16.1` (which is officially the latest).

You can read more about the issues we fixed here:

https://github.com/cloudant-labs/cloudant-follow/issues/54

https://github.com/cloudant-labs/cloudant-follow/issues/50

https://github.com/cloudant-labs/cloudant-follow/issues/47